# Other options to resize barcode for zebra printer using ZPL?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I want to print a Code 128 barcode with a Zebra printer. But I just can't get exactly where I want because the barcode is either too small or too big for the label size of 40x20 mm. Is there anything else I can try besides using the `^BY` (Bar Code Field Default) module width and ratio?

```
^XA^PQ2^LH0,0^FS
^MUM  
^GB40,20,0.1,B^FS
^FO1.5,4
^BY0.2
^BCN,10,N,N
^FD*030493LEJCG002999*^FS
^FO8,15
^A0N,3,3
^FD*030493LEJCG002830*^FS
^MUD
^XZ
```

Above script gives me a label that looks like this: 
[image]

But when I just decrease the module width to 0.1 (which is the lowest) the barcode becomes too small and may be problematic to scan with a hand scanner:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Code-128 is a fixed-ratio code, so you would appear to have the choice of two sizes. You may be able to solve the problem by using a 300dpi printer in place of a 200.

If you can change the format (and I'm intrigued by the barcode and readable being different values) then you could save a little by printing *one* number-sequence and *one* alpha-sequence, as an even count of numerics will be encoded as alphabet C so you'd save one change-alphabet element.

Do you really need the `*` on each end?

Otherwise, perhaps code 39 (which prints the `*` if you use the print-interpretation-line option) would suit your purposes better.

Comment: The user is a 300 dpi printer and set to that. The barcode value and the clear text below it are only different because of a copy-paste mistake. Those values will match. Unfortunately the sequence cannot be changed and the `*` are required although in my opinion they are alse useless. Code 39 barcode is even bigger than 128.

Comment: Hmm - well, it would appear that you're stuck. To get a decent-sized barcode you could possibly use a 204 dpi printer and BY0,1. Otherwise, I'd suggest it's up to the geniuses dictating the format to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Another Possibility is to do on the fly code-set changes, Try something like

```
^XA^PQ2^LH0,0^FS
^MUM  
^GB60,20,0.1,B^FS
^FO1.5,4
^BY0.2
^BCN,10,N,N
^FD>:*>5030493>6LEJCG>5002830>6*^FS
^FO8,15
^A0N,3,3
^FD*030493LEJCG002830*^FS
^MUD
^XZ
```

This will allow less symbols to encode your data 
If you can structure content to have all the alpha chars a one end or the other.
or (Depending on your firmware) you could use auto `^BCN,10,N,N,N,A`